# Is it possible to use the “minimal” algorithm for interactive adding?

Tags: git, diff, git-add

Git doesn't always choose hunk boundaries correctly, when calculating a changeset from snapshots. `git diff` has a `--diff-algorithm` option that allows some tweaking in this regard; `git diff --minimal` sometimes gives better results than `git diff` alone.

Is there a way to get the same optimised changeset layout also for `git add -p` (which basically shows the `diff` hunks interactively)? It doesn't seem to allow the `--diff-algorithm` option.

Comment: `git add -p` is (embedded within) a perl script (in `$(git --exec-path)/git-add--interactive`, so you could copy and edit it a bit.  Hm, on further examination I see it inspects `diff.algorithm` from your configuration, so you can just set that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR version

```
git -c diff.algorithm=minimal add -p
```

(requires Git version 1.8.4 or newer).

#### Details

Moving this from comment to answer after the last bit of research:

Since Git version 1.8.4, the interactive add perl script (which implements `git add -p`) obeys the `diff.algorithm` setting in your git configuration.  This went in with [commit 2cc0f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc0f53b53e7d5456ec45713a201142754d69249) (12 Jun 2013) by [John Keeping (`johnkeeping`)](https://github.com/johnkeeping).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 91fc159](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91fc159745eccb0830c9719642d07617c8100b41), 27 Jun 2013)</sup>  :

> When staging hunks interactively it is sometimes useful to use an
>       alternative diff algorithm which splits the changes into hunks in a more
>       logical manner.  This is not possible because the plumbing commands
>       called by add--interactive ignore the "diff.algorithm" configuration
>       option (as they should).
>
> Since add--interactive is a porcelain command it should respect this
>       configuration variable.  To do this, make it read diff.algorithm and
>       pass its value to the underlying diff-index and diff-files invocations.
>
> At this point, do not add options to "git add", "git reset" or "git
>       checkout" (all of which can call git-add--interactive).  If a user
>       wants to override the value on the command line they can use:
>
> ```
>    git -c diff.algorithm=$ALGO ...
> ```

(with a fix in [commit e5c2909](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5c29097826be86e2f18139491cdf9c830c7fa3e) (23 Jun 2013) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster); the fix is also in 1.8.4).