# How to get better hunks in git add interactive patch mode?

Tags: git, diff, patch, interactive, git-add

I often use `git add -p somefile` to interactively stage only parts of the in the given file. However, if the file has more complicated changes, the default diff goes awry and so do the hunks offered by the interactive patch command.

The `git diff` command has a number of options to improve or customize the diff output, including the extremely useful `--anchored=<text>`, but are there any means get better hunks from `git add -p`?

Comment: `git add -p` is actually a perl script: `git --exec-path` tells you where it lives; look in this directory for `git-add--interactive`. You should be able to modify this to invoke `git diff` with `--anchored=<text>`.

Comment: use emacs magit

Comment: Could you perhaps show one of these hunks that bothers you?  Better than what? In what text?

Comment: @torek it won't always be a perl script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382252/6309

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the following :

- Define a [custom hunk header](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header) suitable for your case as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111535/10155936)
- Try a different [diff algorithm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-algorithmpatienceminimalhistogrammyers) by passing it as a standalone configuration parameter to `git add -p` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510081/10155936)

  ```
  git -c diff.algorithm=<algo-name> add -p
  ```

  The available diff-algorithms as per git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-algorithmpatienceminimalhistogrammyers),

> **-diff-algorithm**={*patience|minimal|histogram|myers*}

> Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:
>
> **default**, **myers** The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the
> default.
>
> **minimal** Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is
> produced.
>
> **patience** Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.
>
> **histogram** This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support
> low-occurrence common elements".

- Use [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) to manually select lines/hunks you wish to stage for commit as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276943/10155936) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123852/10155936) (*See the screenshot of the tool below*)

[image: git-gui]

- [Modify the hunk's size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891676/10155936) itself
- Set this [`diff.indentHeuristic`](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffindentHeuristic) parameter

  ```
  git -c diff.indentHeuristic=true add -p
  ```

From git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffindentHeuristic),

> **diff.indentHeuristic**
> Set this option to true to enable experimental
> heuristics that shift diff hunk   boundaries to make patches easier to
> read.

However, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400027/10155936)

> With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you don't even have to specify --indent-heuristic anymore (since it is the default for quite some times now).

, this
parameter is set (to true) by default. So probably, try setting it to false if
at all it helps.